# Applying Subdivision surface modifier destroys mesh topology

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv, texture-painting, subdivision-surface

So I made this simple pike fish model and Smart UV unwrapped it (and yes i applied scale) while having the subsurface modifier assigned to the model, not applied. I did merge verts (did nothing) and faces are oriented in a good way, the whole model is in quads (exept eyes). I used Stencil Mapping method to paint the texture on the model. Model does not have faces inside it. [image]

When I apply it, the mesh changes completely. There are vertices floating outside of he model and on its surface. If I delete them the texture goes back to normal. I have no idea what is causing it. When I merge verts after applying subsurface it deletes 13k+ verts.[image]
[image]

This is how the mesh looks like before applying subsurface if you are wondering
[image]

Comment: Your outliner shows there are 22 meshes inside your object - could it be that there are more parts that are now fighting for space to be seen as the shape is committed with the modifier? Can you hide each mesh part in edit mode one at a time by selecting Linked(L) and discover if there is a duplicate inside the object somehow?

Comment: The 22 objects are teeth parented to the pike (every single one of them is a different object), even after clearing the parent the "glitch" still occurs. Hitting "L" just selected the whole model.                                   
 But I have Solved the issue!! I selected the whole mesh before applying the modifier then applied it. When I went back to edit mode the only thing selected was the "right" mesh with a well painted texture on top.    Thanks so much for your response, becouse of it i launched blender (even though it is midnight) and solved it. Thanks!

Comment: can you share your blend file